# Запятая на стыке союзов: где и стоит

Tags: синтаксис, пунктуация

"Cто лет одиночества" Габриэля Гарсии Маркеса:

Он пытался околдовать ее чарами своей фантазии, обещанием чудесного мира, где стоит только обрызгать землю волшебными составами, и деревья начинают плодоносить по воле человека, где за бесценок можно купить самые разнообразные лекарства для лечения болезней.

Разве между "где" и стоит" не нужна запятая? *Стоит* здесь вроде союза "если"

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте вынуть придаточное: Он пытался околдовать ее чарами своей фантазии, обещанием чудесного мира, где ... и деревья начинают плодоносить по воле человека. Роль союза И похожа на ТО: стоит...,и..., если..., то... Вынули - роль поменялась, И стала частицей, как даже. Здесь ГДЕ относится к сложноподчинённому предложению целиком, а не к главной его части:...обещанием чудесного мира,
 где / стоит только обрызгать землю волшебными составами, и деревья начинают плодоносить по воле человека/, где за бесценок можно купить самые разнообразные лекарства для лечения болезней.